# MEAN server on hadoop

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, server, mean

I'm a new to hadoop. I want to run a single node hadoop for testing my application. Also I want to read data from different sensors using a http server and save their data to Mongodb and then at some specific times save them on hdfs.
Is it possible to run my MEAN (mongodb-express-angular-node) server in parallel with the single node hadoop at one computer?

Comment: If your question is: to run a HTTP server (using MEAN stack) on a Hadoop system. Yes, you can. No reason for - you can't do that.